# In R, how do I apply regexes to specific parts of a string that contains a pattern?

Tags: regex, r, substring

I have a dataframe (**trip**) that contains a column (**SNP**). It looks like this (but longer, and it has 192 levels):

```
SNP
C[T->C]T
C[G->C]A
G[A->C]A
C[T->C]C
C[C->A]G
T[G->A]C
...
```

I want to pattern match and replace on the following criteria:

```
gsub("G->T", "C->A", trip)
gsub("G->C", "C->G", trip)
gsub("G->A", "C->T", trip)
gsub("A->T", "T->A", trip)
gsub("A->G", "T->C", trip)
gsub("A->C", "T->G", trip)
```

but ALSO, if one of the patterns listed above is found, I want the string in which it's contained have additional substitutions applied. Namely:

```
if ((grep(G->T|G->C|G->C|A->T|A->G|A->C), trip$SNP)==TRUE){
   substr(trip$SNP, 1,1) <- tr /ATCG/TAGC/; #incompatible perl syntax?
   substr(trip$SNP, 8,8) <- tr /ATCG/TAGC/;
   }
```

As in, if any of these patterns--G->T, G->C, G->C, A->T, A->G, or A->C--is found in a string in trip$SNP, replace the 1st and 8th characters in that string according to this regex: tr /ATCG/TAGC/;

Desired output, with changes in bold:

SNP
C[T->C]T
C[G->C]A
G[A->C]A
C[T->C]C
C[C->A]G
T[G->A]C

to:

SNP
C[T->C]T
**G[C->G]T
C[T->G]T**
C[T->C]C
C[C->A]G
**A[C->T]G**

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I don't entirely get what you're doing (`tr /ATCG/TAGC/` where are your quotes here?) but I'm 99.9% certain it would work to paste a `%s` in to string when you do the first `gsub` and then use `sprintf` to later insert what you want in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SNP <- as.character(trip$SNP)
SNP
[1] "C[T->C]T" "C[G->C]A" "G[A->C]A" "C[T->C]C" "C[C->A]G" "T[G->A]C"
i <- grep("(A|G)->", SNP)
SNP[i] <- chartr("ACGT", "TGCA", SNP[i])
SNP
[1] "C[T->C]T" "G[C->G]T" "C[T->G]T" "C[T->C]C" "C[C->A]G" "A[C->T]G"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably add on packages to do this better and faster but this would work (I don't think I have exactly what you want but it's close enough you can adapt for what you're after).  Note that the first 14 lines are just reworking your data, the solution is only a few lines.

```
dat <- read.table(text="trip
C[T->C]T
C[G->C]A
G[A->C]A
C[T->C]C
C[C->A]G
T[G->A]C", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

replace <- matrix(c("G->T", "%s[C->A]%s",
"G->C", "%s[C->G]%s",
"G->A", "%s[C->T]%s",
"A->T", "%s[T->A]%s",
"A->G", "%s[T->C]%s",
"A->C", "%s[T->G]%s"), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)


for(i in 1:nrow(replace)) {
    dat$trip[grepl(replace[i, 1], dat$trip)] <- replace[i, 2]
}

sprintf(dat$trip, "/ATCG/TAGC/", "/ATCG/TAGC/")

## [1] "C[T->C]T"                     "/ATCG/TAGC/[C->G]/ATCG/TAGC/"
## [3] "/ATCG/TAGC/[T->G]/ATCG/TAGC/" "C[T->C]C"                    
## [5] "C[C->A]G"                     "/ATCG/TAGC/[C->T]/ATCG/TAGC/"
```

Comment: this successfully replaces the strings in between [], but my output contains %s in replaced rows. head(test$SNP)
[1] "C[T->C]T"   "%s[C->G]%s" "%s[T->G]%s" "C[T->C]C"   "C[C->A]G"   "%s[C->T]%s"

Comment: Then you didn't do the last step with `sprintf`, in any event you are spending time asking questions rather than spending time making original question clearer.  I'm hazy as to what you want.  Your best bet is to show the desired output from above.  And make sure your data you posted looks like the data you're working with.

Comment: I did use sprintf, to no avail. I've updated the post with desired output. "tr /ATCG/TAGC/" is a perl regex that replaces A with T, T with A, etc. I just need a way to do it in R.